# How to remove the last character in a JTextField when delete key is pressed

Tags: jtextfield, keylistener, keyevent

I want to use a key listener to detected each time the user enters text into a field. Each time the key event is triggered I want to get the `length()` of the text in the `JTextField`. If the `length >= limit` then I want to disable editing. However, if the **delete key** is pressed I want to remove the **last character** in the `JTextField` and `setEditable(true)`.

How do I remove the **last character** in the `JTextField`?

```
public void keyPressed (KeyEvent evt) {}
public void keyReleased (KeyEvent evt) {

    int limit = 1;
    JTextField text = (JTextField)evt.getSource();

    if (text.getText().length() >= limit) { 
        text.setEditable(false); 
    }
    else {
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {   
            answer ="";
            text.setEditable(true);
        }           

public void keyTyped (KeyEvent evt) {}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the entire event handler in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater block.

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt)  
    { 
        final int limit = 1;
        final int keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
        final JTextField text = (JTextField)evt.getSource();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                if (text.getText().length() >= limit) 
                { 
                    text.setEditable(false); 
                } 
                else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) 
                {       
                    answer =""; 
                    text.setEditable(true); 
                }
            }
        });                        
    }
```

Since event handling and Swing GUI updates are both done on the Event Dispatch Thread, this may be needed to allow the text.getText() method to retrieve all of the entered text.

Comment: Great trick!  I've had problems with this type of event in the past and this is the best workaround yet.  Hey, erietha, you should consider accepting his post as the solution.